# How to get role's comment from the PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

Given the role name `someone`, how to get a comment defined with clause:

`COMMENT ON ROLE someone IS 'THIS IS A ROLE COMMENT';`

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good way to find how to retrieve this kind of information is to check the help for `psql` and find the command that would display this information.

In this case, it is the `dg+` command.

Once you know the command, you can enable printing of the internal SQL queries of the `psql` tool to find out how it retrieves that information. This is done by starting `psql` using the `-E` parameter.

If you do that, you'll see:

```
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dg+
********* QUERY **********
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, pg_catalog.shobj_description(r.oid, 'pg_authid') AS description
, r.rolreplication
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
**************************

                                List of roles
   Role name   |            Attributes             | Member of | Description
---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------
 someone       |                                   | {}        | THIS IS A ROLE COMMENT
```

It's not clear from your question if you just want *some* method to see the comment, then `dg+` is probably enough. Otherwise you can adjust the SQL query that is used by `psql` to your needs, e.g.:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.shobj_description(r.oid, 'pg_authid') AS description
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
where r.rolname = 'someone';
```

Note: \du and \dg are the same command in psql. Both are maintained [for historic reasons](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18782.1248206562%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

Comment: Thank you. It's all clear now. And yes, I've looked for the SQL query to be executed.

Answer (score 7):

Roles are shared over all databases in a cluster. The comments on those shared objects are contained in the `pg_shdescription` system catalog. You can get the comment for a role like so:

```
SELECT rolname, description AS comment
FROM pg_roles r
JOIN pg_shdescription c ON c.objoid = r.oid;
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the accepted answer's query:

```
select r.rolname, psd.description
from pg_catalog.pg_shdescription psd
inner join pg_roles r ON r.oid = psd.objoid
inner join pg_class c ON c.relname = 'pg_authid'
inner join pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace AND n.nspname = 'pg_catalog';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `psql`'s `\du+` outputs roughly:

```
\du+ someone
 Role name |          Attributes           | Member of |      Description
-----------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------------------
 someone   | Password valid until infinity | {}        | THIS IS A ROLE COMMENT
```

where you can read the comment in the `Description` column.

Comment: Lol, went looking for a solution to this and found my own answer. :D Too bad I can't upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple query is:

`select objoid::regrole, description from pg_shdescription where classoid='pg_authid'::regclass`