# Getting role comments in PostgreSQL by query

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql allows adding comments to roles and users. For example I've added a comment to role "myuser" by using this SQL command:

```
COMMENT ON ROLE myuser IS 'User comment...';
```

My question is: If I want to use a SQL-command to get all users along with their respective comment - how would I do this? What would be the appropriate query for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get role's comment from the PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480553/how-to-get-roles-comment-from-the-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use built-in function [shobj_description(object_oid, catalog_name)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE)

```
SELECT *, shobj_description(oid, 'pg_authid') AS comment
  FROM pg_roles;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.usesysid, u.usename, d.description
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user u
   LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_shdescription d
      ON d.objoid = u.usesysid
         AND classoid = 'pg_catalog.pg_authid'::regclass;
```